# 'No space left on device' on mounted NFS device

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, nfs, network-attached-storage

On NFS Server:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdf2           103212320  85090308  12879132  87% /export18
```

On Client Server:

```
ip-xxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:/export18
                 103212320  85090304  12879136  87% /export18
```

But if I try to create file, I got this message:

```
touch: cannot touch `/export18/test': No space left on device
```

I have unmounted the volume and run fsck on it:

```
fsck -t ext3 /dev/xvdf2
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
/dev/xvdf2 has gone 484 days without being checked, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/xvdf2: 6553600/6553600 files (4.8% non-contiguous), 21683897/26214400 blocks
```

Maybe 4.8% for non-contiguous is a bit high, but... Still not able to write.

**Question:** What might be the reason of inability to write to the volume if there is only %87 is used?

**EDIT:**

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvdf2           6553600 6553600       0  100% /export18
```

Comment: you ran out of inodes. So on that partition you have a ton of very small sub 4k files.

Comment: I will create new larger volume with XFS then

Comment: @Mike, how have you counted file size? 103212320K / 6553600 = 16127

Comment: no idea what your inode size is but a lot of small files will fill up your inodes but if they are under the set inode size df will still show free space but there are no more inode's to put anything

Comment: This is clear. I meant how have you come up with 4k files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You maybe ran out of inodes. Please check `df -i` on NFS server.

Comment: You are right! Please see EDIT.

Comment: Why is it 6553600 for 100G? Shouldn't it be 105689415680 ÷ 2^13 = 12901540 by default (This volume was not created by me)?

Comment: I see why, it is controlled by /etc/mke2fs.conf